# Crontab give error while script has no issues while running from command line

Tags: shell

I am executing a script from crontab which is failing and gives below error (in /var/log/messages logs)

```
2020-10-20T13:10:01.010834+01:00 AFGBE01-MN cron[1471]: (CRON) CAN'T FORK (do_command): Resource temporarily unavailable
2020-10-20T13:10:01.011251+01:00 AFGBE01-MN cron[1471]: message repeated 2 times: [ (CRON) CAN'T FORK (do_command): Resource temporarily unavailable]
2020-10-20T13:11:01.011487+01:00 AFGBE01-MN cron[1471]: (CRON) CAN'T FORK (do_command): Resource temporarily unavailable
2020-10-20T13:12:01.012671+01:00 AFGBE01-MN cron[1471]: message repeated 5 times: [ (CRON) CAN'T FORK (do_command): Resource temporarily unavailable]
```

When I am running from command line script is running properly. I am trying stop & start one process in scirpt.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date`|tee -a /tmp/new_test.txt
STATUS=`netstat -lntp | grep :9666 | awk -F ' ' '{print $6}'`
echo "Current Status" $STATUS |tee -a /tmp/new_test.txt
if [ -z "$STATUS" ]
#if [ $STATUS != "LISTEN" ]
then
/etc/init.d/<process> stop  | tee -a /tmp/new_test.txt
sleep 10
/etc/init.d/<process> start | tee -a /tmp/new_test.txt
fi
```

Comment: My very first attempt to solve this problem will be to check if cron service is running or not, you could check it on your system once. Though I have never faced this kind of issue but I would start it from doing this only.

Comment: I checked cron service  is running , I can see status output in /tmp/new_test.txt file.

Comment: same problem did u solve?